# How to import my python module in windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, build, module

I have generated a python module from cpp project using `pybind11`, I have run my project without any error in Ubuntu 16.04. Now I want to run my project in Windows 10 and I encounter error for `import skfmm_dev` which is my module.
The error is :

> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing skfmm_dev: The specified module could not be found.

I added the location of `skfmm_dev.cp39-win_amd64.pyd` to the system path, but still have this problem, I don't know whether there exist conflicts that I can not load my module or not?

I use `pybind11 v2.6.2` and `Python 3.9.6`, I also used Mingw64 with ninja to build my project. The version of my compiler is `gcc 8.1.0`.

I even `print(sys.path)`, and it contains the path of my module. Can any one please help me?

Comment: I installed python from `choco install python` than installing from windows store.